# Stop displaying logger output to console from dependencies

Tags: java, xml, logging, configuration, log4j

I have a few Maven dependencies in my Java project that clutter the console output with redundant log info. I want to disable such logging.

Setting the `additivity` property to `false` might help. But could not use it properly.

I am looking for a `log4j.xml` config that will only print log output (`warn`, `error`, ...) from my project and not from any dependencies.

Comment: Have you yet a  log4j.xml /  log4j.properties file ?

Comment: Check your log4j.properties?

Comment: I use a log4j.xml taken from `www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example/`
OK to use log4j.properties file as well if works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `log4j2.xml` was overriding all other configs. As of now, I have switched that dependency off. Maybe `log4j2 > log4j` hence the issue. Also, `XML` gets a higher priority over `properties` as I have seen somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect all the third party lib logs in a target appender, use another appender for your app

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,thirdPartyLibAppender 
log4j.logger.com.yourapp=debug, yourAppAppender
log4j.additivity.com.yourapp=false

# define where do you want third party lib logs to land : in a file
log4j.appender.thirdPartyLibAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.thirdPartyLibAppender.append=true
log4j.appender.thirdPartyLibAppender.file=/tmp/app.log
log4j.appender.thirdPartyLibAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.thirdPartyLibAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %c:%m%n

# define where do you want your app logs to land : stdout
log4j.appender.yourAppAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.yourAppAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.yourAppAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %c:%m%n
```

Setting additivity to false will prevent that your app logs end in the `thirdPartyLibAppender`

**In those 2 lines, don't forget to replace com.yourapp by the top level package name**

```
log4j.logger.com.yourapp=debug, yourAppAppender
log4j.additivity.com.yourapp=false
```

Comment: Sorry being a dumb, `thirdPartyLibAppender` is just a name right? I hope it does not point to any specific appender beacsue I dont know any specific name :( and what will be real value for `yourapp` :'(

Comment: Yes just a name, you can change it, define the appender as you like.

Comment: can you please give me a complete log4j.properties file with real value where myapp logs on console and 3rdpartyapp in a file :)

Comment: Could you post your config file ?

Comment: very kind of you but still no joy, I am missing something. Looks like a `log4j2.xml` in a dependent jar is overriding my `log4j.properties`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62794/discussion-between-saik0-and-toyonos).

Comment: That will be against the organizational policies. But the `log4j.properties` is exactly the same as you have posted above. I just replaced `com.yourapp` with `com.company.department.project.test`

Comment: It starts with -
`2014-10-10 12:17:05,904 DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/com/.../xxx.jar!/log4j2.xml]`